# When does the boost asio call async_read_some callback?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

Trying to understand boost asio library, I implemented an async echo server. I ask the `tcp::socket` to do an `async_read_some` for a small amount of data, namely 9 bytes (chosen for testing to be a small number), i.e. `socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf, 9), callback)`. Then I feed small amounts of data to the server and the read command only seems to callback when it has a full 9 bytes to read, not immediately after writing, say, 4 bytes, as I expected. What determines when the callback occurs and why doesn't it occur as soon as some data is available on the socket?

Comment: it does occur when the OS signals that data is available. Much of that will be dependent on the hardware buffers, IRQ levels etc. It's basically implementation defined.

Comment: @sehe So there's nothing for me to do different with the boost calls, if I use  `asyn_read_some`? ie it's possible that I could never be called back while the socket is open and there is data to be read?

Comment: You could possible tune the sysctls and driver parameters. Perhaps you can use specific hardware. You can disable [Nagle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) on the sending side. You can make sure no routing equipment rearranges packets etc.

Comment: That being said, I think there are minimum guarantees on allowable latency even with say Nagle's algorithm enabled (default on TCP connections). So "it's possible that I could never be called back while the socket is open and there is data to be read?" doesn't seem true. But I don't have a source to link with that. (Should not be hard to find, really)

Comment: @sehe What I was seeing was that I was manually writing to the tcp socket from a little test client. On the test server, when async_read_some returned, it would `fprintf(stderr, stuff)`. I would write a few characters and the server would just sit there. It was only after writing enough the it did something, and enough was 9. It did seem like it would hang for ever with a few characters having been sent.

Comment: If by "manually writing" you mean e.g. `netcat`, then line-buffering is definitely the culprit.POSIX stdin/stdout is also traditionally buffered.  Look at utilities (setvbuf, unbuffer) or maybe your netcat has options to disable it.

Comment: @sehe No, I have another program that is making a series of calls to `boost::asio::write`, the non-async write function, on the other end of the socket. I am stepping through it in gdb so I can control when those writes occur.

Comment: Beware the async_read_some returns immediately. Make sure buf doesn't go out of scope before that.

Comment: @StackedCrooked I don't the OP is confused about that. He's asking _when the callback fires_. Otherwise he'd be asking why there's no data in his buffer.

Comment: It's just that I remember experiencing a similar issue, which turned out to be UB due to buffer having gone out of scope. It's a guess :P

Comment: @StackedCrooked in that case, I guess the buffer access would have raised a segfault/AV on the thread that processed the callback. I don't know what would happen, but I suppose that the callback would not happen, no matter how many bytes were available:(

Comment: @MartinJames when I was playing around with seeing what happens as I changed the various examples I found, I found async_read will in some situations call back with errno 14, i.e. EFAULT, instead of segfaulting when asked to write out of bounds. Albeit, I was looking at reading more bytes than the buffer had alloced rather than the buffer having gone out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

The [`socket.async_read_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) operation has the same completion conditions as its synchronous counterpart, the [`socket.read_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some/overload1.html) operation.  The operation is considered complete when either:

- One or more bytes of data has been received successfully
- An error occurs that would prevent data from being received

Upon completion of the operation (success or failure), the [*ReadHandler*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html) will be posted into the `io_service` for deferred invocation.  At this point, the *ReadHandler* may be invoked by any thread servicing the `io_service`.

---

When small amounts of data are being written to a socket, such as in the problem description, one typically observes the behavior of data not being sent until subsequent data is written to the socket because of [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm).  In short, many systems will attempt to mitigate IP/TCP congestion by concatenating small outbound messages into a single message that is then sent.  To explicitly disable this behavior on a per-socket basis, set the [`boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/no_delay.html) option:

```cpp
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
// ...
boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option(true);
socket.set_option(option);
```

When in doubt, monitor the wire traffic with a packet analyzer, such as Wireshark or tcpdump, on both the sender and receiver.  One can often use these tools to at quickly identify whether the problem is on the sending or receiving side.  Upon identifying the offending side, one often has to dive into kernel, driver, or hardware documentation to identify configurations that may be the source of the problem.